# How to Isolate css?

Tags: html, css, widget, shadow-dom, isolation

I have a project in development which will be something like gadget or widget for loading it in other websites. **It Won't be an Iframe**
but when i load it as a widget in other websites there is lot's of **CSS** conflicts.
I searched for solution and find [ShadowDOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM).
I tried it for solving problem! but didn't work!

I appreciate it if you help me for this problem.

```html
<div id="%REACT_APP_ROOT_ID%" data-plugin="%PLUGIN_ID"></div>
    <script>
      const widget = document.getElementById('rcroot');
      widget.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
      widget.shadowRoot.innerHTML = widget.innerHTML;
      widget.innerHTML = '';
    </script>
<div>
```

Comment: can you alter the css to just add id everywhere? Like `#my.widget div{}` `#my-widget .box{}` etc. and use some nasty little `!important` here and there?

Comment: @Pepo_rasta
even i do this. there will be also some problems. for example my side-menu will work on all of the document. i mean when i open it, it will open from the parent website.
because of that the most secure way is to isolate all of the project.
but the question is how can i do that?
and thank you for your comment!

Comment: React and W3C standard Web Components are not Best Friends (due to Reacts (kinda outdated) virtual DOM approach). Search for blogs on what is required so React understand Web Components